# Can I make html video autoplay and preloaded?

Tags: html

```
<video autoplay loop id="introVid">
  <source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=****" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

To make the video autoplayed on the website I used this code, but there's some delay before this 22MB video loads which I want to avoid if possible. I don't think I can use preload for this without giving up on autoplay, so is there another language I can use for this situation?

Comment: When do you want to preload the video? If you want the video to start as soon as the page loads, you can only preload it *before* the page loads, which is only possible if you have control over the previous loaded page.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "another language"? This is not a HTML limitation.

Comment: maybe compressing the video or converting it to a gif is a way to go then? Alternative would be using a player that reports when video is ready to be played.

Comment: I'm sorry if my post was vague. I'm pretty new to coding and haven't learned things beyond html and css so I was wondering if there's something in javascript or jQuery to make it possible. If I were to use the <video preload></video> in html to make the video load when the page loads (not after the page loads) it wouldn't work, because preload and autoplay cannot work together...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is prepare a smaller video, much more compressed and shorter. Load this initially and when loading completed begin loading the full video. Keep a track of the time and replace the source and forward it to the right time once the loading of the full video completes.

AFAIR all the video streaming things require the video to be served (streamed) in a particular way.